# Scatter plot matrix

Tags: python, matplotlib, matrix, seaborn

I'd like to get a scatter plot for all my matrix.

I found the module seaborn, and I did something like this.

```
import seaborn as sns

data_ = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Machine Learning/iris.csv', skiprows=1, delimiter=',')
sns.pairplot(data_)
```

[image]

I was wondering how could give it color, like in this image.

[image]

Also I was wondering if is there some way to see my plot matrix from Matplotlib, without make my own one by one. Thanks a lot!

Updated:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2645             try:
-> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'variety'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:
-> 2648                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2649         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2650         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'variety'
```

Comment: Please edit the question such that the code will show up in a code section like `this` and not inside the image. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just do `hue='species'`:

```
sns.pairplot(data_, hue='species')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work, I guess it because in my case, my csv doesn't have an attribute like 'species' but 'variety'. But it doesn't work even when I use `hue='variety'`

Comment: Hue is exactly for that purpose. What happens with your data when you use `hue='variety'`?

Comment: Your data does not have a column named `variety`. Maybe you should include a printout of `data_.head()` or similar.

Comment: OK, I love you. I just noticed the error, I used 'skiprows=1' when I loaded the data, so I deleted the name of the columns. Now it fixed, and works perfectly, thanks a lot!